# Problem making an OOK current signal using pvcvs

Tags: communication, simulation, cadence

I am trying to make an OOK current signal using pvcvs in cadence (I tried pcccs but i couldn't find out what the settings were and it didn't work), and in order to change the output to current i used a vccs as seen in the figure below:
[image]

it works fine when i haven't yet added the vccs but as i add it, i get the error that i have a negative giga volts voltage somewhere and that my system is unstable. can someone please suggest a way to make a current OOK signal or help me with resolving the error?

Comment: What's connected to the output? How much voltage does the vccs have to produce to drive its current through the load?

Comment: I solved the issue thanks, I had designing problems @ThePhoton

Comment: @Faleme, please post an accept an answer telling how you solved the problem. That will tell the SE system the problem is solved and keep it from being promoted to the front page in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the direction of the vccs was not correct and I also lowered the currents by changing the sizes of my MOSFETs and the issue is resolved now